# Did Intel have low chip yields due to a clerk hand-checking blank wafers?

Tags: computers

In [this blog post](https://www.cringely.com/2020/07/22/mark-zuckerbergs-pact-with-the-devil/) Bob Cringley recounts the following story (abriged for brevity here):

> There was a time in the early 1980s when Intel suffered terrible quality problems. [..] The problem was caused by dust, the major enemy of computer chip makers.
>
> [The blank wafers were made by Monsanto, who worked hard to ensure that their wafers were dust-free. This didn't solve the problem.]
>
> Monsanto engineers hired a private investigator to tail the next shipment of wafers to Intel. Their private eye uncovered an Intel shipping clerk who was opening incoming boxes of super-clean silicon wafers and then counting out the wafers by hand into piles on his super-unclean desktop, just to make sure that Bob Noyce was getting every silicon wafer he was paying for.

This is a nice little story about the perils of running a giant company, which makes me suspicious; it smells of urban legend. I haven't been able to find any other report of this story, so I'm wondering if anyone knows the truth about this. Did it really happen?

**Edit:** The story is taken from Cringley's 1996 book [*Accidental Empires*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0887308554).

Comment: It does seem very fishy that a major company like that wouldn't have measures in place to prevent such expensive parts from being opened in a non clean environment.

Comment: I read that story probably 30 years ago, including the bit about “making sure the CEO got all the wafers he was paying for”, and I think it was in a book, but I can’t really remember. Obviously can’t say if it’s true or not, but definitely something that wasn’t made up recently. @Joe I bet nobody ever thought that kind of thing could happen. It was a completely unanticipated threat vector. Wouldn’t happen again because now Intel (or TMSC or whoever) knows the story.

Comment: @gnasher729 I question how it could be an unanticipated threat vector as I question how it would not be noticed that the items where unpacked before they made it into the clean rooms that are setup for production. Are you suggesting that no one would question why the boxes are getting opened before that point?

Comment: @gnasher729 On the website Cringley says that this story is taken from his book "Accidental Empires" (https://www.amazon.com/Accidental-Empires-Silicon-Millions-Competition/dp/0887308554) Would it be that one?

Comment: @JoeW I agree there are lots of obvious questions; wouldn't Monsanto have labelled the packages with "Only to be opened in clean-room conditions"? How did this 3rd party private eye gain access to Intel's goods inwards bay? But I'm looking for evidence.

Comment: Non-supporting evidence from [this 1997 article](https://www.nytimes.com/1997/01/27/business/a-wafer-maker-s-formula-for-success-equal-parts-sand-and-grit.html): **Thus, MEMC officials say, after it lost mighty Intel as a customer during the 1980's because it was unable to invest enough to meet Intel's needs, MEMC was unable to get Intel to resume purchases until last year.**

Comment: The story is probably BS. What is real is that Intel received NSF funding to measure other companies wafer quality. https://books.google.com/books?id=WlgTAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA112 (an Monstanto's wafers were found inferior to the Japanese ones.)

Answer (score 5):

An earlier source is [The Mac Almanac](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Mac_Almanac/pQUkXbq92DIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22despite%20intel%27s%20also%20immaculate%22%20opening&dq=%22despite%20intel%27s%20also%20immaculate%22%20opening&printsec=frontcover) (1994 by Sharon Zardetto Aker) ([alternative link](https://archive.org/details/macalmanac00aker)) at page 390:

> At one point (the actual point is obscured by the mists of time—call it a couple of decades ago), the Intel company blamed its poor production yields of computer chips on Monsanto, the company providing silicon wafers used to make the chips. Monsanto already had a spic and span facility, but it spent several millions of dollars in research and revamping. To no avail: Intel's yields were still very low, despite Intel's also-immaculate environment.

> Monsanto got tired of being unfairly blamed for the contaminants. Someone at the company had a brainstorm: if neither company was at fault, why not check what was happening to the wafers during shipment? Ah ha! A clerk at Intel, upon receiving each shipment of wafers, opened the boxes and counted the wafers by (presumably dirty) hand to make sure they were all there.

Comment: Yes, I heard this story several years ago.